# getting two value from response ajax and assign each one of them to two different ID's

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I was trying to get two values from AJAX response. I'm using get element by ID and it's working perfectly. I'm just trying to echo more than one value in php and get them as a response to set one value in a div element and the other one gets assigned to a hidden input value. Here is my code:

```
    <script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("thermospace_cart_1_ID_Add").value = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("Hint").innerHTML = this.responseText;

            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","forms.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

PHP code to handle Ajax request:

```
$q =$_GET['q'];
switch($q){
case "6008":  
$getrow= "SELECT ProdID, ProdPrice WHERE ProdID = 6008 ";
$list = mysql_query($getrow, $data) or die(mysql_error());
$rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($list);
$totalRows_list = mysql_num_rows($list);
echo $rs['ProdPrice'];   // I want this value assigned to ID1
echo $rs['ProdID'];      // and this value   assigned to ID2

break;
```

Comment: any help will be really appreciated!!

Comment: in the `select` statement shouldn't there be a `from` clause?

Comment: the use of `mysql_query` is deprecated and removed in PHP 7

Comment: yes there is an html form that is sending the data to the ajax but I didn't post the code for it @Lambda7

Comment: I was talking about the last **SQL** query

Comment: They mean missing FROM TABLE in the query

Comment: + You tagged your question Jquery, that could save you from the browser specifics of handling XmlHttpRequest

Comment: I just noticed that! its actually a copying mistake when I copied the code to here

Answer (score -1):

I think you should return the values via JSON. For example, instead of

```
echo $rs['ProdPrice'];   // I want this value assigned to ID1 
echo $rs['ProdID'];      // and this value   assigned to ID2
```

You should do something like that

```
echo json_encode($rs);
```

In the javascript part, parse the responseText like this:

```
var rs = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
var prodPrice = rs.ProdPrice;
var prodId = rs.ProdID;
```

Comment: You missed something vital in the query